# How do I create an array that contains numbers and char?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I create an array that contains numbers and char?
I need do create an array the should be looked like this: 3 / 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

An array can contain only a single type of value, but you can create array of object.

this might help you - http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/array-of-objects